# Story about a world where a person's hair color depends on their power

Tags: story-identification, books

Then there's this girl whose hair is white I think. Someone just told me about it and I don't really know anything else about it.

Comment: While we can try to help (*Warbreaker* is the first to pop to mind, though it doesn't really fit entirely), I'm not sure we'd be able to get a concrete answer if this is just something you heard of and not something you read.

Comment: Of course, I understand. Though something that would fit that description could easily be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your description made me think of a children's fantasy book called Tatsinda, by Elizabeth Enright, published in the early 60s.  It's about an isolated land where all the inhabitants have snow white hair and blue-green eyes, except for the orphan girl Tatsinda.  She has brown eyes and golden hair, and is treated badly because she's different - until a giant kidnaps her and threatens to destroy the kingdom.

From [Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/elizabeth-enright/tatsinda/):

> "The tale has everything-- an enchanted land; a special language; a lovely orphan girl of strange and foreign aspect; a prince whom she loves; a cranky, spunky witch; a greedy, villainous giant who roars out hair-curling songs; abduction, rescue, and true love rewarded-- all emerging from magic, and touched with the magic of good story telling.

It's for very young readers, but the overall theme is about not discriminating against people who are different.  I loved it as a kid - I probably read it when I was about 9 or 10 years old, and still remember it.